# VS Code: edits with 4-spaces, saves with 2-spaces

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-code, indentation

How do I make "Format on Save" use the same indentation as when I'm editing?

E.g. after writing the following snippet (lines are auto-indented with 4-spaces):

[Edit with 4-space indents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtu3L.png)

However, when I enable "Format on Save", the saved file uses 2-spaces for indentation:

[Saved with 2-space indents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjYyj.png)

Answer (score 8):

To answer my own question...

I'm using the *Prettier* extension, and it had the number of spaces per tab set to 2.

With the "Format On Save" option enabled, `"editor.formatOnSave": true`, VS Code uses the configured code formatter, which is *Prettier* in my case.  The default tab width used by *Prettier* is 2.

After setting it to 4, the file is now saved with 4 spaces.  The `Settings.json` is updated with:

```
"prettier.tabWidth": 4,
```

I thought *Prettier* would apply to both editing and saving.  Evidently, *Prettier* formatting is only being applied during save.  I also notice that "Format Selection", `Ctrl-K Ctrl-F`, is not using *Prettier* tab spacing either.

It would be nice if I could set the *Prettier* tab width to match the editor setting, so that I only have to change this in one place.  Is that possible?

Matt.

Comment: Prettier is doing his job when saving, formatting to 4 spaces, but while im typing vs code force the 2 spaces and its pretty annoying get a pre format in 2 spaces. Dont know how to change it.